# getting sum of a column in php is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sum

i'm trying to get the sum of values in a column inside php but it's not working at all while the query works fine when testing in MySQL here's the code (updated with full code)

```
require('../_req/base.php');
$getCartQ = "select * from user_product inner join cart inner join products inner join users on user_product.User_ID = cart.User_ID and user_product.User_ID = users.User_ID group by cart.User_ID";
$getCartR = mysql_query($getCartQ);
?> <table align="center" width="1271" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

 <?php
 while($cartRow = mysql_fetch_array($getCartR)){

     $sumQ = "select SUM(Total) as total from user_product where Status = 'active' and user_product.User_ID = '$cartRow[User_ID]'";
     $sumR = mysql_query($sumQ) or die(mysql_error());
     $sumRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($sumR);
     $cost = $sumRow['total'];
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $cartRow['Full_Name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cartRow['State']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cost; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
 }
 ?>
 </table>
 <?php
mysql_close($connect);
```

when i try to echo $cost i get nothing just a blank space what's wrong with that code ?

Comment: You should not use the mysql api for php. Use MySQLi or PDO. It has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0

Comment: Just echo the connection object just before the query $sumQ and check whether it exists or not.

Comment: There should be some built in magic function that autoposts that "dont use mysql_*, use SQLi/PDO" mantra as an auto-comment to any question that has "mysql_query" inside a code block. Think of all the manhours wasted every day people spend writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 user_product.User_ID = '$getCartR[User_ID]'";
```

to

```
 user_product.User_ID = '{$getCartR['User_ID']}'";
```

Comment: i was just about to say this as well... next time put all code at once :)

Answer (score 1):

do

```
echo mysql_error();
```

at the end and tell me what it's showing. You'll have your answer right there

Comment: it's written as you suggested

Comment: supplied resource is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in

Comment: did you even start a db connection with `mysql_connect('host','user','pass');` followed by `mysql_select_db('dbname');` before running the query?

Comment: why i get this error while te query works inside MySQL (phpmyadmin) ?

Comment: yes sure connection has started and there's another query just before it getting some other data

Comment: Did you place `echo mysql_error();` after running the failing query? Because i dont understand it saying not a valid mysql link. Did you maybe do `mysql_close();` somewhere before running the failed query or the echo I told you to add?

Comment: sure not closing the connection is not even close to this query

Comment: Please put `echo mysql_error();` directly after the line with `mysql_query(`...`);`

Comment: have you done what i said in my previous comment? what was the output?

Comment: that was the output but after clearing the cache it worked fine "supplied resource is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in" thanks @nl-x

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the cache and everything worked fine i don't know what this has to do with the cache thanks all for your help i appreciate it